# How to get Launch options in Application()

Tags: android, kotlin

I would like to get the Launch options in my Application() class.

I start my application with Activity Manager: `am --es name Joe`
I can get this value with the following code written in kotlin: `intent.getStringExtra("name") ?: "undefined"`

However, I cannot get this "name" value in `class MyApplication: Application() {...}`

Is there any solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

No. Those are extras on the `Intent` that is starting your activity. They are not directly available to anything else.